# Using Return in bash

Tags: bash

I'm wanting this script to print 1,2,3.. without the use of functions, just execute two.sh then carry on where it left off, is it possible?

```
[root@server:~]# cat testing.sh                                  
#!/bin/bash
echo "1"
exec ./two.sh
echo "3"

[root@server:~]# cat two.sh                                     
#!/bin/bash
echo "2"
return
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`exec`, if you give it a program name <sup>a</sup>, will *replace* the current program with whatever you specify.

If you want to just *run* the script (in another process) and return, simply use:

```
./two.sh
```

to do that.

For this simple case, you can also execute the script in the context of the *current* process with:

```
. ./two.sh
```

That will not start up a new process but will have the side-effect of allowing `two.sh` to affect the current shell's environment. While that's not a problem for your current `two.sh` (since all it does is echo a line), it may be problematic for more complicated scripts (for example, those that set environment variables).

---

<sup>a</sup> Without a program name, it changes certain properties of the *current* program, such as:

```
exec >/dev/null
```

which simply starts sending all standard output to the bit bucket.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, just run:

```
echo "1"
./two.sh
echo "3"
```